# Analysing a jet of water by thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, entropy, fluid-statics

Consider a jet of water flowing from a pipe. I get a contradiction when I try to analyse the situation.

1. **Using Thermodynamics:** As the jet of water fall down , the water forms a fine jet.The entropy change is negative as the disorderness of the system decreases . Hence at higher temperatures , their is a possibility that $\Delta$G for this process is positive , meaning the process is not spontaneous.
2. **Using Fluid Dynamics:** As the jet of water fall down , the water forms a fine jet . Its velocity increases due to attraction from Earth and hence its area decreases or in other words the equation $$ A_1 V_1 = A_2 V_2$$ is satisfied.

So I get a contradiction as thermodynamics tells me that this should not happen naturally whereas fluid dynamics suggests the opposite. What is the mistake?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that the "disorderness" of the fluid decreases? In the second case, if you get droplet formation, all sorts of things are happening, and your simple continuity equation does not apply anymore in the form you gave.

Comment: @Pirx As the jet falls down , its radius decreases , hence its external surface area. Now the particles on the surface have more energy , hence if surface area decreases , the no . of particles having more energy decreases. This suggests me that the entropy of the system decreases .

Comment: Using thermodynamics, in the absence of viscous dissipation, the change in entropy of the water is zero and its change in free energy is zero.

Comment: I don't see your argument for entropy decrease. In any case, the first thing to notice is that the system in question is not a closed system, so all sorts of interesting things can happen.

Comment: @Pirx I think InquisitiveMind is referring to the entropy change of the water parcels between the top and bottom of the jet.  Each parcel is being treated as a closed system.

Comment: But they are not, most certainly not when the jet disintegrates into droplets.

Comment: Your argument about entropy decrease is not at all clear, as pointed out by @Pirx. You should show an explicit calculation. What is your system? Have you assumed that it is isolated? Whose area is decreasing and why? If you consider a fluid parcel, then even if its radius decreases, it is elongated along fall direction. If fluid density and temperature remain constant, then all its thermodynamic properties including its entropy will remain constant, as pointed out by Chester Miller in a different way.

Comment: @Zero Your comment is an answer to my question

Comment: @InquisitiveMind: My thermo said entropy $H = \int dQ/T$, and neither Q nor T is changing.

Comment: Happy to unwittingly answer your question :-) Next time when you post a question, make it thorough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument that , the entropy of the system decreases while flowing out of the pipe is not justified. Consider a packet of water , as it comes out of the pipe , its thermodynamic quantities remain constant.